# Return to Merchant

Tags: paypal, return

[Return to Merchant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqXEu.png)

> Return to Merchant Error
>   We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please go back to the merchant and try using a different payment method.

Payment was working fine with sandbox credentials. As soon as I changed my client id into production with live credential it started showing me this error.
My currency is INR. Can't find the problem exactly. Help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing research finally payment is completed with paypal.

Return to Merchant Error comes when you are accepting payment in INR and login using another country paypal account. For accepting payment in INR you must login with Indian paypal account.

For accepting both national and international payment you must complete KYC process which require your real documents. Paypal will confirm your document within a day. Then only you can accept any payment with paypal.